# Visual C Code Crashing when attempting to check if file exists using function fopen_s(...) != NULL

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, fopen

IDE: Visual C++ 2010

Coding an app that performs a simple dictionary attack. It opens a file and searches for a particular 'string' (a password) in that file. If found it alerts the user 'Pass Found!' else 'Good! Secure password'

In case this password dictionary file is not found (d8.txt), it should display an error message. I read about fopen_s and it throws a NULL pointer if file not present. So I coded:

```
if((fopen_s(&fp, "d8.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
         printf("Error! File Not Found!! ");
```

However the program just crashes when it reaches this point and MS Debug Library says "Debug Assertion Failed! Expression (str != NULL)"

What am I doing wrong?

The complete code if you need it:

```
printf("\n[i] Now initiating a Dictionary Attack on the Password...");

FILE *fp;
if((fopen_s(&fp, "d8.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
         printf("Error! File Not Found!! ");
             printf("Is the d8 Dictionary present?");
             exit(1);
       }

while(fgets(FileTemp, 30, fp) != NULL) {
    if((strstr(FileTemp, UserPass)) != NULL) {
        PassFound=1;
    }

if(PassFound)
    printf("\nA match found!! Your Password is not strong!");
else
    printf("Good! Your Password was not Cracked by the Preliminary Dictionary Attack.");
```

Comment: Why are you opening the same file and the same stream descriptor **twice?**

Comment: Oops! My bad. That was something I did while writing the code again here on stackoverflow in a hurry. Edited it now. Any ideas on the why the debug error?

Comment: Are you sure it is that line?  In what routine is the assertion?

Comment: @Pranshu Please next time copy and paste code, that avoids such errors. As to the problem: in case it indeed was your actual code, then the stream not being `NULL` is **the** problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fopen_s doesn't return null pointer on fail, but it sets the file pointer (fp) to null. The return value would be either 0 (on success) and an error number (on fail). So you should go for:

```
   int errno=0;
   if((errno=fopen_s(&fp, "d8.txt", "r")) != 0) {
      // Here you can check errno to give more detailed error messages..
      printf("Error! File Not Found!! ");
   } else
   { // read the file ... }
```

Check to see different error numbers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1(v=vs.100).aspx
and here for fopen_s documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks it works! I actually found these [link] (http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-searching-for-strings-in-a-text-file) people using the NULL thing and I thought it was correct

Comment: @Pranshu well you didn't read it correctly. It uses "if((fopen_s(&fp, fname, "r")) != NULL)" to check for errors. You used == instead. Also, you should know that NULL is just a constant equal to zero. Though it's a good practice to use NULL when checking it against pointers (like fopen's return value) and stick with 0 when checking against numbers (like fopen_s's return value).

Answer (score 1):

The correct way:

```
if((fopen_s(&fp, "d8.txt", "r")) == 0)
```

fopen_s returns `errno_t` which is `typedef int errno_t`.

`0 file opened non zero file not opened`

valter

Comment: Ok I tried this code but still the same error::: FILE *fp;
    if((fopen_s(&fp, "d8.txt", "r")) == 0) {
    printf("File NOT Found!! ");
    }
   
 

 
  while(fgets(FileTemp, 30, fp) != NULL) {
  if((strstr(FileTemp, UserPass)) != NULL) {
   PassFound=1;
  }

Comment: That is I substituted the line "if((fopen_s(&fp, "d8.txt", "r")) == 0)" but still the same error. Debug Assertion Failed... fgets.c"